# Are the "in"s and "on"s in the following grammatically correct: "We will run the executable in the dev environment on machine dev-linux-07"?

Tags: grammar

Some colleagues think it would be more grammatically correct to read:
"We will run the executable *on* the dev environment on machine dev-linux-07"

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98217/discussion-on-question-by-yiezkel-schoenbrun-are-the-ins-and-ons-in-the-fol).

Answer (score 1):

Your coworkers are incorrect; it should be ***in***.

Dev environments are used to either protect your code from the public, or to protect the public from the code, or both. Functionally, an environment is an isolated capsule where you can do experiments with little risk. So I believe this to be an accurate use of the word ["environment"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/environment):

> ***environment*** noun
>
> 1 : the circumstances, objects, or conditions by which one is surrounded

The word "surrounded" in the definition is telling: you'd never be *on* your surroundings. You are *in* your surroundings.

Note: I believe the M-W definition 4 ("a computer interface...") is a red herring. Despite that the word in your sentence is being used to describe something involving a computer, your statement is not referring to the interface. Generally speaking, an environment comprises the toolsets and resources available to a process that is initiated via some interface. If your sentence referred to an interface, I think the correct word would be *via* or *through*; still not *on*.